# Merge two lists of different size into one matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Given that:

```
X = [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
y = [1, -1, 0]
X = np.asarray(X, np.uint8)
y = np.asarray(y, np.int8).T
con = np.concatenate(X, y)
print(con)
```

Where `X` is supposed to be a dataset of size (3,4) and `y` is the class labels of each row in the matrix `X`. For instance, `X[0]= [1, 0, 1, 1]` has a class label equal 1 in `y[0]`, i.e., `y[0]=1`. I want to merge `X` and `y` together into one matrix of size (3,5) where the new column is the `y` list. However, the previous code gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    con = np.concatenate(X, y)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create an array of appropriate size and then assign the values from the lists?

Comment: Have one more look at the docs! Hint: ```concatenate((a1, a2, ...),...```. (and i would prefer concat to the aproach in above comment)

Comment: are you after `con = np.hstack((X, y.reshape(-1,1)))`?

Comment: @MaxU Thank you Max. That's exactly what I am looking for. Don't have enough points to vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with

```
np.concatenate(X, y)
```

is that the 2nd argument is supposed to the axis, not the 2nd array.  `np.concatenate((X, y), axis=1)` would work if `X` and `y` both have the same shape.  But they don't.

```
In [181]: X = [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
     ...: y = [1, -1, 0]
     ...: 
In [182]: np.column_stack((X,y))
Out[182]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

`column_stack` makes sure the inputs have the right shape to concatenate as columns:

```
In [183]: np.concatenate((X,y),axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-a97a3320ed3e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((X,y),axis=1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

In [184]: np.concatenate((X,np.array(y)[:,None]),axis=1)
Out[184]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

But be careful when joining arrays with different classes of data.  `y` is class labels.  But what is `X`?  Same sort of units?  If it contained the floats the joined array would also be floats.  I suspect this is just a step toward using some other code where class labels makes more sense, such as `pandas` or one of the machine learning packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with the lists, and convert to matrix (2-dim array, to be more specific) at the end:

```
X = [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
y = [1, -1, 0]
myList = [foo[0]+[foo[1]] for foo in zip(X,y)]
myMatrix = np.array(myList)
```

Gives you:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

But I would store the label-row pairs in a dictionary:

```
{foo[1]:foo[0] for foo in zip(X,y)}
```

Gives you:

```
{-1: [1, 1, 1, 1], 0: [1, 0, 0, 0], 1: [1, 0, 1, 1]},
```

which gives you much more flexibility, and you can still go to a numpy array like so:

```
np.array([v+[k] for k,v in myDict.items()])
```